# Haskell: parse error on input `|'

Tags: haskell

I am getting this error:

> sky.hs:3:5: error: parse error on input `|'

This is the code:

```
sky list  
    | (length list) /= 1 = reverse (last(even (sky list)) : reverse(odd list)
    | otherwise = list
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I have made sure that there are no tabs, just 4 spaces before the `|` symbol. This might seem like a novice question but I am a beginner in Haskell.

Comment: Not enough close parens.

Comment: Note that **1.** you don't need half of these parentheses anyway **2.** I don't think your code can possibly terminate, because you have a recursion of the form `sky list = f $ sky list` – the recursive call works on exactly the same data again, so this can never come to an end. (In fact it doesn't _need_ to come to an end because Haskell is lazy, but I don't think this would work, either. And **3** _always use type signatures_, even (or, _especially_) if you only want to demonstrate a simple example. This makes it so much easier to understand what your code is supposed to be doing (or _not_).